# Add link rel to head of Magento

Tags: magento, templates, seo

Is there a quick and clean way to add a rel link in the head section of Magento.

Examples would include home,index,next,prev,canonical.

I'd like to be able to do this from either a helper, block, template.
See this for more information

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Answer (score 2):

You should search in magento core code, for example the one that handles REL canonical tags :  class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View` :

In a block for example :

```
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $category->getUrl());
```

but you can do that wherever you can access a loaded layout.